# Comma usage: "In July of 2012 ..." or "In July of 2012, ..."

Tags: american-english, punctuation, commas, software-bugs

Consider the following sentence:

> In July of 2012 Jesse informed us that she was engaged to be married
>   and asked if she could add her fiancée to the lease,
>   beginning the 15th of August 2012.

Is it any more or less correct to place a comma after the first date?

> In July of 2012, Jesse informed us that she was engaged to be married
>   and asked if she could add her fiancée to the lease,
>   beginning the 15th of August 2012.

Assuming one is no more correct than the other, does this change the meaning of the sentence, or is it pure style?

Bonus question: Word tells me that it's improper to place a comma after the "August" at the end of the sentence. I've always been taught that a comma should be used to separate the year from the rest of the date. Was I taught wrong, or is Word lying to me?

Comment: Thanks, but you should write that as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is correct with or without the comma. But the comma introduces a break/pause, which can be helpful in a longer sentence, and *personally* I would include it.

As regards formatting of the date, British usage used to be to separate month & year with a comma, but more recent usage omits the comma. (I can't speak for US usage, although I suspect that the comma is more likely to be included.)

In any event, for both questions, it is primarily a matter of style: there is no right or wrong way for either point.

Comment: You shouldn't use a comma only to introduce a pause. In this case, the comma is acceptable, not because of the pause, but because it offsets an introductory clause. More [here](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/commas/) and [here](http://www.pnc.edu/engl/writingcenter/comdon.html).

Comment: @J.R. I said that "the comma [***does***] introduce a break/pause". I did **not** say "use a comma ***to*** introduce a pause" - and would not do so (unless it were in a position where an optional comma were acceptable for other reasons). I was addressing the issue of whether a comma was appropriate/necessary *in that particular place*. I was **not** discussing when/where to use a comma in general. If you look at my profile you will see that I used to write pseudo-legal documents professionally (for 20y). I may not know all the terminology - but I **do** know how to write grammatically.

Comment: Trevor: My remark wasn't meant to imply that you didn't know how to write; it was more meant as a hint to others who might read your answer, and be led into thinking that you **should** use a comma when you want to introduce a pause. Perhaps I could've said, "_One_ shouldn't use a comma..." instead of "_You_ shouldn't use a comma..." At any rate, I'm glad we agree.

Comment: I came for the grammatical advice, but I stayed for the beautiful pedantry.

Answer (score 2):

*In July of 2012* can be seen as a weak interruption to the sentence, and a comma after *2012* can be justified for that reason.

There’s no reason to put a comma after August. In fact, in British English, the date would probably as *15 August 2012*.

Comment: This is really nitty-gritty, but in the case where the purpose of the document is to establish a series of events, where the date that the author learned of things is just as important as when said things occurred, is treating it as a weak interruption less correct?

Comment: Also, you say "can be justified." Are you implying that, taken alone  with no other context, both forms of the sentence are correct?

Comment: In practice, I don't think anyone would notice or care whether there was a comma after *2012* or not.

Answer (score 1):

About your question about comma between month/day and year:

The 16th ed. of *Chicago Manual of Style* gives the following format:

> 1 January 2014

or

> January 1, 2014

What I understand is that the comma is used in the second example because you don't want a visual confusion between the two separate numbers—*not* to offset the year as such.

Hence, it would be:

> 1 January 2014 is a good day.

But

> January 1, 2014, is a good day.

*I assume* that the second comma in the second example is there to prevent any misunderstanding about the meaning of the sentence, in view of the first comma.

PS: *New Hart's Rule* is on its way, so no idea as of now about what *that* says.